# Please help with my problems retrieving email using POP3 protocol

Tags: c#, compact-framework, pop3

I am using C# and Microsoft .Net Compact Framework 1.0. I tried to implement the POP3 protocol using the `System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream` and `TcpClient` classes. I am able to log in and receive email and save the attachments with some email servers. But for some, I keep running into problems.

I read the size of the email message by sending the `List <Index>` command. In some situations I get a size significantly smaller than the actual value.  For example, for the same EMail:

```
Actual size: 577860, Returned size: 421096 using Exchange 2007
Actual size: 561005, Returned size: 560997 using Exchange 2003
```

Why don't I ever get the right size? The following the code I am using.

The size of the email never matches the size of the `StringBuilder` at the end of `PopRead` procedure. I am not able to read the email reliably because the Email size is not reliable and the `DataAvailable` property of the `NetworkStream` is sometimes false, even if there is more data that can be read.

I observed that the `DataAvailable` property is false more often when I am trying to connect to the email server over the air (using data-plan) than when using the internet connection of the computer through activesync.

If it helps, the email servers are Exchange 2003 and Exchange 2007.

```
private bool POPRead(StringBuilder strBuffer, long lngFetchMailSize)
{
   const int bufferSize = 1024;

    byte[] inb;
    if (enc == null)
    {
        enc = new ASCIIEncoding();
    }

    try
    {
        if (lngFetchMailSize > 0 && lngFetchMailSize < (32 * bufferSize))
        {
            // limit the size of the buffer as the amount of memory
            // on Pocket PC is limited.
            inb = new byte[lngFetchMailSize];
        }
        else
        {
            inb = new byte[bufferSize];
        }
        Array.Clear(inb, 0, inb.Length);
        bool bMoreData = true;
        long iBytesRead = 0L;
        int bytesReadInThisRound = 0;

        int numberOfTimesZeroBytesRead = 0;

        while (bMoreData)
        {
            bytesReadInThisRound = this.nsPOP.Read(inb, 0, inb.Length);
            iBytesRead += bytesReadInThisRound;

            if (bytesReadInThisRound == 0)
            {
                numberOfTimesZeroBytesRead++;
            }
            else
            {//If on a retry the data read is not empty, reset the counter.
                numberOfTimesZeroBytesRead = 0;
            }

            strBuffer.Append(enc.GetString(inb, 0, bytesReadInThisRound));
            Array.Clear(inb, 0, bytesReadInThisRound);
            // DataAvailable sometimes gives false even though there is
            // more to be read.
            bMoreData = this.nsPOP.DataAvailable;
            // Use this number (5), since some servers sometimes give the size
            // of the email bigger than the actual size.
            if ((lngFetchMailSize != 0 && !bMoreData)
                && (iBytesRead < lngFetchMailSize)
                && numberOfTimesZeroBytesRead < 5)
            {
                bMoreData = true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string errmessage = "Reading email Expected Size: " + lngFetchMailSize;
        LogException.LogError(ex, errmessage, false, "oePPop.POPRead");
        Error = ex.Message + " " + errmessage;
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        GC.Collect();
    }
    return true;
}
```

The following procedure is used to get the size of the email message:

```
private long GetMailSize(int index)
{
    StringBuilder strBuffer = new StringBuilder();
    const string LISTError = "Unable to read server's reply for LIST command";
    if ((this.POPServer != null) && (this.nsPOP != null))
    {
        if (!this.POPWrite("LIST " + index))
        {
            return -1L;
        }
        if (!this.POPRead(strBuffer))
        {
            this.Error = LISTError;
            return -1L;
        }
        if (!this.IsOK(strBuffer))
        {
            return -1L;
        }
        string strReturned = strBuffer.ToString();
        int pos1 = strReturned.IndexOf(" ", 3);
        if (pos1 == -1)
        {
            this.Error = LISTError;
            return -1L;
        }
        int pos2 = strReturned.IndexOf(" ", (int)(pos1 + 1));
        if (pos2 == -1)
        {
            this.Error = LISTError;
            return -1L;
        }
        int pos3 = strReturned.IndexOf("\r\n", (int)(pos2 + 1));
        if (pos3 == -1)
        {
            this.Error = LISTError;
            return -1L;
        }
        long mailSize = 0;
        Int64.TryParse(strBuffer.ToString(pos2 + 1, pos3 - (pos2 + 1)).Trim(), out mailSize);
        return mailSize;
    }
    this.Error = NotConnectedError;
    return -1L;
}
```

Hope I gave all the information needed for solving the issue. Any help or pointer in the right direction would be a lot of help.

Thanks,
Chandra.

Answer (score 1):

Your error may lie in using the ASCIIEncoder the way you are.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/38b953c8.aspx):

> Data to be converted, such as data
>   read from a stream, can be available
>   only in sequential blocks. In this
>   case, or if the amount of data is so
>   large that it needs to be divided into
>   smaller blocks, the application should
>   use the Decoder or the Encoder
>   provided by the GetDecoder method or
>   the GetEncoder method, respectively.

Since you are decoding a little bit at a time, it is possible it is decoding portions of the stream incorrectly.

I would change your code to use a [decoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.asciiencoding.getdecoder.aspx), or to read the entire message at once, then decode it with the GetString() member.

As an additional sanity check you could use the message size that RETR <index> returns and see if it matches what LIST  returns. If they don't match, I at least, would go with what RETR returns.

Answer (score 0):

POP3 is a tricky protocol. So many different servers to deal with, many with their own obscure quirks. If this is a production app, I would seriously consider buying a 3rd party component that's been thoroughly tested.

Comment: Hi,  
  I tried a couple of components (trial versions), but they were not much help. Some of the kept throwing exceptions, and I kept running into OutOfMemory exception when I had to download a large (approx 3 MB) attachement. It would be nice if you have a suggestion. 

Thanks,
Chandra

Answer (score 0):

Since an email should end with a period, I would do this comparison for termination of the loop.

Instead of

```
 if ((lngFetchMailSize != 0 && !bMoreData)
       && (iBytesRead < lngFetchMailSize)
       && numberOfTimesZeroBytesRead < 5)
  {
      bMoreData = true;
  }
```

I would write it as

```
  if(!bMoreData 
    && strBuffer.ToString(strBuffer.Length - 5, 5) != "\r\n.\r\n")
  {
       bMoreData = true;
  }
```